# Passing Data notification services to activity But didn't get any response

Tags: android, firebase

I am passing data from notification services to activity using event bus. but not getting any message on main activity. here my code is.

```
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new String("Send data"));

    @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEvent(String event) {
    // your implementation
    Toast.makeText(this, event, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(String message) {

    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

 public void onEventMainThread(MessageEvent event) {
     Toast.makeText(this, event + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

     InstaOrderApp.getInstance(this).setCurrentactvity(this);

     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
     updateTableQty();
   }
```

Any one please help me where is issue ?
thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you receive the notification?

Comment: @diegoveloper yes i am getting notification

Comment: did you register Event bus in your activity ??

Comment: @HemantParmar yes i have register also

Comment: in which method you unregister your eventbus?

Comment: @HemantParmar i have unregister on destroy

Comment: @MehulTank try to register your event in oncreate().

Comment: i have also added in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159112/discussion-between-mehul-tank-and-hemant-parmar).

Answer (score 1):

Did you register the event bus on your  onStart method?

```
@Override

public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

}
```

Comment: Yes i have also try that onstart but still it is not working

Comment: Could you put your logcat?

Comment: D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class java.lang.String

 D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent

Comment: Hmm probably you are subscribing to the eventbus after you receive the notification

Comment: yes i have subscribe after receive notification on message receive

Comment: Oh, then you need to register the eventbus before you receive the notification :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159109/discussion-between-mehul-tank-and-diegoveloper).